# Repeating the same animation 6s after first one using animate.css [Edited]

Tags: javascript, animate.css

I want to repeat shake animation using animate.css after 6 seconds once.

Here is the code I've tried so far.

the first part of animating works great but the second one. it just doesn't.

With JavaScript, I can setTimeout to fire after 6 seconds, remove the shake animation, then add shake class back to the element, and the problem is exactly here, although setTimeout fires, second shake animation doesn't appear (The animation which is expected to appear after 6 seconds)

```
// First Part: Adding animation to the object 

    document.querySelectorAll(".profile")[userA_Index].classList.add('animated', 'shake', 'slow', 'delay-1s')


//Second Part: Now I remove the first shake animation and add the second one after 6 seconds, But unexpectedly the animation here doesn't work...

    setTimeout(function(){ 
    document.querySelectorAll(".profile")[userA_Index].classList.remove('animated', 'shake')
    document.querySelectorAll(".profile")[userA_Index].classList.add('animated', 'shake', 'slow', 'delay-1s')
    }, 6000);
```

Comment: And what's the problem exactly? I can't test that your code. Please read this carefully: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Sorry for my bad English :( I've edited the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In lack of proper vocabulary, i'll explain it like this:

This is treated as a single DOM modification, as you add and remove the same class in the same DOM update, and looks as as if nothing changes.

Add a second setTimeout, to push a separate DOm update, after the first has taken place :

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
    document.querySelectorAll(".profile")[userA_Index].classList.remove('animated', 'shake');
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.querySelectorAll(".profile")[userA_Index].classList.add('animated', 'shake', 'slow', 'delay-1s')
    }, 16); // can work for 0 also, but i usually like to leave a frame in between
}, 6000);
```

Comment: Thank you... It worked... Plus one ... But why it looks as if nothing changes when I add and remove the same class in the same DOM update?

Comment: In lack of proper vocabulary :)

Comment: This will help in understanding why it works, better than I am capable of explaining atm (way too much celebrating today). https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ

Comment: Better try using `requestAnimationFrame` instead of 16ms as not all browsers work at 60 FPS in every environment.